# Travis CI Deploy by SSH Script/Hosts issue

Tags: django, ssh, travis-ci

I have a django site which I would like to deploy to a Digital Ocean server everytime a branch is merged to master. I have it mostly working and have followed this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/nickbclifford/16c5be884c8a15dca02dca09f65f97bd).

.travis.yml

```
language: python
python:
- '2.7'
env:
 - DJANGO_VERSION=1.10.3
addons:
   ssh_known_hosts: mywebsite.com
git:
  depth: false
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K *removed encryption details* -in travis_rsa.enc -out travis_rsa -d
- chmod 600 travis_rsa
install:
- pip install -r backend/requirements.txt
- pip install -q Django==$DJANGO_VERSION
before_script:
- cp backend/local.env backend/.env
script: python manage.py test
deploy:
  skip_cleanup: true
  provider: script
  script: "./travis-deploy.sh"
  on:
    all_branches: true
```

travis-deploy.sh - runs when the travis 'deploy' task calls it

```
#!/bin/bash

# print outputs and exit on first failure
set -xe

if [ $TRAVIS_BRANCH == "master" ] ; then

    # setup ssh agent, git config and remote
    echo -e "Host mywebsite.com\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    ssh-add travis_rsa
    git remote add deploy "travis@mywebsite.com:/home/dean/se_dockets"
    git config user.name "Travis CI"
    git config user.email "travis@mywebsite.com"

    git add .
    git status # debug
    git commit -m "Deploy compressed files"
    git push -f deploy HEAD:master
    echo "Git Push Done"
    ssh -i travis_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null travis@mywebsite.com 'cd /home/dean/se_dockets/backend; echo hello; ./on_update.sh'


else

     echo "No deploy script for branch '$TRAVIS_BRANCH'"

fi
```

Everything works find until things get to the 'deploy' stage. I keep getting error messages like:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for mywebsite.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address *REDACTED FOR STACK OVERFLOW*
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
* REDACTED FOR STACK OVERFLOW *
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/travis/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/travis/.ssh/known_hosts:11
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/travis/.ssh/known_hosts" -R mywebsite.com
Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Script failed with status 128
```

INTERESTINGLY - If I re-run this job the 'git push' command will succeed at pushing to the deploy remote (my server). However, the next step in the deploy script which is to SSH into the server and run some postupdate commands will fail for the same reason (hosts fingerprint change or something). Or, it will ask for travis@mywebsite.com password (it has none) and will hang on the input prompt.

Additionally when I debug the Travis CI build and use the SSH url you're given to SSH into the machine Travis CI runs on - I can SSH into my own server from it. However it takes multiple tries to get around the errors.

So - this seems to be a fluid problem with stuff persisting from builds into the next on retries causing different errors/endings.

As you can see in my .yml file and the deploy script I have attempted to disable various host name checks and added the domain to known hosts etc... all to no avail.

I know I have things 99% set up correctly as things do mostly succeed when I retry the job a few times.

Anyone seen this before?

Cheers,
Dean